# React hooks how to skip specific useEffect after initial useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code, how do I prevent `AsyncStorage.setItem` from being called 2 times on initial render? It's called with `[]` and whatever is loaded from `AsyncStorage` because `logs` was updated. The perfect solution should not call `setItem` at all, because the `logs` was just retrieved from `AsyncStorage`.

```
const AsyncStorage = require("@react-native-community/async-storage")

const useStore = () => {
  const [logs, setLogs] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("logs").then((newLogs) => setLogs(newLogs));
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    //Don't want to setItem on initial load or when `logs` was just loaded.
    AsyncStorage.setItem("logs", JSON.stringify(logs));
  }, [logs])

  const addLog = (newText) => {
    setLogs(logs => [
      {text: newText, createdAt: new Date().getTime()},
      ...logs,
    ]);
  }

  return {
    logs,
    addLog,
    //...many other functions that update logs
  }
}
```

Comment: so, essentially you want to use it like a `componentDidUpdate` hook?

Comment: You could write a hook that ignores the first change..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think wrapping your set state method is a cleaner way to control when logs persisting should take place. Something like this:

```
const AsyncStorage = require("@react-native-community/async-storage")

const useStore = () => {
  const [logs, setLogsState] = useState([])
  const persistLogsRef = useRef(false)

  const setLogs = (updatedLogs) => {
    persistLogsRef.current = true
    setLogsState(updatedLogs)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("logs").then((newLogs) => setLogsState(newLogs));
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    //Don't want to setItem on initial load or when `logs` was just loaded.
    if (persistLogsRef.current) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem("logs", JSON.stringify(logs));
    }
  }, [logs])

  const addLog = (newText) => {
    setLogs(logs => [
      {text: newText, createdAt: new Date().getTime()},
      ...logs,
    ]);
  }

  return {
    logs,
    addLog,
    //...many other functions that update logs
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ref that acts as a flag whether to allow settings logs or not.

```
const AsyncStorage = require("@react-native-community/async-storage")

const useStore = () => {
  const [logs, setLogs] = useState([]);
  const allowSettingLogs = React.useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("logs").then((newLogs) => setLogs(newLogs));
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    //Don't want to setItem on initial load or when `logs` was just loaded.
    if (allowSettingLogs.current) AsyncStorage.setItem("logs", JSON.stringify(logs));
  }, [logs])

  const addLog = (newText) => {
    allowSettingLogs.current = true;
    setLogs(logs => [
      {text: newText, createdAt: new Date().getTime()},
      ...logs,
    ]);
  }

  return {
    logs,
    addLog,
    //...many other functions that update logs
  }
}
```

Comment: This will still call `AsyncStorage.setItem("logs", JSON.stringify(logs));` after the first useEffect sets logs.

Comment: You could use a ref to check for the updates. I have updated the code above.

Comment: I'm reluctant to add `allowSettingLogs.current = true` to all my functions that update `logs ` though, there is addLog, deleteLog, updateLog.... Is there a way to just add mark it on the `AsyncStorage.getItem` line?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wrap `useEffect` and make it ignore the first change.

```js
const useEffectIgnoringFirstChange = (fn, deps) => {
    const firstCallRef = useRef(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (firstCallRef.current) {
            firstCallRef.current = false;
            return;
        };

        fn()
    }, deps);
}
const useStore = () => {
  const [logs, setLogs] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("logs").then((newLogs) => setLogs(newLogs));
  }, [])

  useEffectIgnoringFirstChange(() => {
    //Don't want to setItem on initial load or when `logs` was just loaded.
    AsyncStorage.setItem("logs", JSON.stringify(logs));
  }, [logs])

  const addLog = (newText) => {
    setLogs(logs => [
      {text: newText, createdAt: new Date().getTime()},
      ...logs,
    ]);
  }

  return {
    logs,
    addLog,
    //...many other functions that update logs
  }
}
```

Comment: This will still call it one time with the logs that were just retrieved from AsyncStorage.

Comment: It could be modified to use a count instead. I think this is a sign of a larger issue of how you're propagating data. Have you looking into using redux?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with, I'm still wondering if this is the best solution, so more elegant solutions are welcome:

```
const AsyncStorage = require("@react-native-community/async-storage")

const useStore = () => {
  const justLoaded = useRef(true);
  const [logs, setLogs] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("logs").then((newLogs) => {
     justLoaded.current = true;
     setLogs(newLogs));
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    //Don't want to setItem on initial load or when `logs` was just loaded.
    if (justLoaded.current === false) AsyncStorage.setItem("logs", JSON.stringify(logs));
    if (justLoaded.current) justLoaded.current = false;
  }, [logs])

  const addLog = (newText) => {
    setLogs(logs => [
      {text: newText, createdAt: new Date().getTime()},
      ...logs,
    ]);
  }

  return {
    logs,
    addLog,
    //...many other functions that update logs
  }
}
```